# Feed a LINQ result into a DataROW

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

This works:

```
var Result = from e in actual.Elements
                         select new
                         {
                             Key = e.Key,
                             ValueNumber = e.Value.ValueNumber,
                             ValueString = e.Value.ValueString,
                             ValueBinary = e.Value.ValueBinary,
                             ValueDateTime = e.Value.ValueDateTime
                         };
```

But this doesn't work:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> Result = from e in actual.Elements
                select new DataRow
                {
                    Key = e.Key,
                    ValueNumber = e.Value.ValueNumber,
                    ValueString = e.Value.ValueString,
                    ValueBinary = e.Value.ValueBinary,
                    ValueDateTime = e.Value.ValueDateTime
                };

DataTable dt = Result.CopyToDataTable(Result);
```

Can you fix it for me? I want the second bit of code to work so that I can put it into the DataTable.  I realize the syntax is totally wrong in #2.  How do you specify a column using LINQ like this?

Comment: What is actual.Elements?  Another DataTable?

Comment: Elements is a dictionary.  The "key" part is a string.  The "value" part is a class with 4 properties -- ValueNumber, ValueString, ValueBinary, ValueDateTime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple extension method that takes any `IEnumerable<T>`, uses reflection to get the `PropertyDescriptor`s associated with T, and creates a `DataColumn` for each

```
public static DataTable PropertiesToDataTable(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

      var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

      foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
      {
          DataColumn dc = dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name,prop.PropertyType);
          dc.Caption = prop.DisplayName;
          dc.ReadOnly = prop.IsReadOnly;
      }

      foreach (T item in source)
      {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
                dr[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item);

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
      }

      return dt;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer much help other than to point you here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into the [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx)

I haven't tested this, but this might get you pointed in the right direction:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> result = (from e in actual.Elements
                              select new DataRow
                              {
                                  Key = e.Key,
                                  ValueNumber = e.Value.ValueNumber,
                                  ValueString = e.Value.ValueString,
                                  ValueBinary = e.Value.ValueBinary,
                                  ValueDateTime = e.Value.ValueDateTime
                              }).AsEnumerable();

DataTable dt = Result.CopyToDataTable(Result);
```

Comment: No, it is not working. It is throwing compilation error DataRow is inaccessible due to protection level. How to resolve that one?