# Convert Datatable GroupBy Multiple Columns with Sum using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want to sum of all TotalImages Column after Group BY but its' showing me error.
any one who can help me what's going wrong.
Remember just want to use from this syntax base and want DataTable  not a List. Kindly if some one help me out will be grateful.

Sample Data:-

```
CountryId | CItyId | TotalImages
1              1        2
1              2        2
1              2        3
1              3        4 
2              1        2
2              2        2
2              2        3
2              3        4 




DataTable dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
 .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["CountryId"], Col2 = r["CityId"]})
 .Select(g => g.Sum(r => r["TotalImages"]).First())
 .CopyToDataTable();
```

[image]

Comment: Share the structure of your `DataTable`, with sample data(if possible).

Comment: @RahulSingh you can assume that 

CountryId | CItyId | TotalImages
1              1        2
1              2        2
1              2        3
1              3        4 
2              1        2
2              2        2
2              2        3
2              3        4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:-

```
DataTable countriesTable = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { CountryId = x.Field<int>("CountryId"), CityId = x.Field<int>("CityId") })
                             .Select(x => new Countries
                                          {
                                              CountryId = x.Key.CountryId,
                                              CityId = x.Key.CityId,
                                              TotalSum = x.Sum(z => z.Field<int>("TotalImages"))
                                          }).PropertiesToDataTable<Countries>();
```

I am getting, following output:-

[image]

Since, We cannot use `CopyToDataTable` method for anonymous types, I have used an extension method took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784791/feed-a-linq-result-into-a-datarow) and modified it accordingly.

```
public static DataTable PropertiesToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        {
            DataColumn dc = dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            dc.Caption = prop.DisplayName;
            dc.ReadOnly = prop.IsReadOnly;
        }
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                dr[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

And, here is the `Countries` type:-

```
public class Countries 
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int TotalSum { get; set; }
}
```

You can use any other approach to convert it to a DataTable if you wish.

Comment: getting issue of your given function when rows adding showing erorr.

this row already belongs to this table.
on this line  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
when i change to dr.Import function then no data returning.
and if i am changing  dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
then its creating very strange table like empty rows duplication.

Comment: @Wajihurrehman - Are you using the same DataTable, I mean the values you posted in your question? I used the same data and it worked as expected, I have shared the output screenshot too.

Comment: no actually it was just a sample. but according to your code it should work for all kind .

Comment: @Wajihurrehman - Hmm I am wondering the same. I re-checked the code and its working fine for me.

Comment: @Wajihurrehman - Hey buddy, While solving some other problem I encontered the same issue `this row already belongs to this table` which you mentioned, Have corrected the code please check.

Comment: Thanx Alot bro.
You kept dr addition line outside foreach loop give reason.

Comment: @Wajihurrehman - Got that from this error `row already belongs to this table` because old code was trying to add the same row again to the DataTable which is obviously not allowed, so inside `foreach` row is constructed and finally added to datatable outside.