# Compare two DataTables and Display the differences in another datatable in LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have two DataTables and I want to display the rows. if both the datatables having the same value, Then mark X in all columns or else select the column with highest value(Eg:DT1: 10,DT2 :5)

Datatable1

```
id       Name      Weight
1        Ship       500
2        Train      600
3        Plane      700
4        Car        800
```

Datatable2

```
  id  Name       Weight
  1    Ship      500
  3    Plane     600
  4    Car       200
```

I want the result to be:

Datatable3

```
id    Name      Weight          Datatable1        Datatable2
  1   Ship      500              X                 X
  2   Train     600              X
  3   Plane     700              X                 X
  4   Car       800              X
```

I have tried the below:-

```
 DataTable Datatable3 = (from a in Datatable1.AsEnumerable() 
                         join b in Datatable2.AsEnumerable() 
                         on a["Name"].ToString() equals b["Name"].ToString()
                         a["Weight"].ToString() equals b["Weight"].ToString() into g 
                         where g.Count() != 1 select a).CopyToDataTable();
 dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Datatable3.DefaultView;
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried the below                     DataTable Datatable3 = (from a in Datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                        join b in Datatable2.AsEnumerable()
                        on a["Name"].ToString() equals b["Name"].ToString()
                        a["Weight"].ToString() equals b["Weight"].ToString()
                        into g
                        where g.Count() != 1
                        select a).CopyToDataTable();
                        
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Datatable3.DefaultView;

Comment: You can edit the question instead and include your code.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check my answer? Let me know if that is what you were expecting. A quick query, I think in DataTable3 above, column `Datatable2` should not have X for id 3 right? Since 700 != 600 :)

Comment: I didn't got the output till now, still finding some issues. But in that case, we need to display the maximum size with(X) to the respective Data tables(i.e.700). Datatable1 with 'X' for Plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have:-

```
DataTable Datatable3 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Union(dt2.AsEnumerable())
         .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Id"))
         .Select(x =>
             {
                 var topWeightItem = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Field<int>  ("Weight")).First();
                  return new Items
                  {
                     Id = x.Key,
                     Name = topWeightItem.Field<string>("Name"),
                     Weight = topWeightItem.Field<int>("Weight"),
                     DataTable1 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Any(z => z.Field<int>("Id") == x.Key 
                                  && z.Field<int>("Weight") == topWeightItem.Field<int>("Weight")
                                  && z.Field<string>("Name") == topWeightItem.Field<string>("Name")) 
                                  ? "X" : String.Empty,
                     DataTable2 = dt2.AsEnumerable().Any(z => z.Field<int>("Id") == x.Key 
                                  && z.Field<int>("Weight") == topWeightItem.Field<int>("Weight") 
                                  && z.Field<string>("Name") == topWeightItem.Field<string>("Name")) 
                                  ? "X" : String.Empty
                    };
               }
         ).PropertiesToDataTable<Items>();
```

Since It is returning an `anonymous` type, you can't use `CopyToDataTable` method, so please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378537/convert-datatable-groupby-multiple-columns-with-sum-using-linq/27385723#27385723) to understand how I converted it into a datatable.

I am getting this output:-

[image]

I have used following type for conversion purpose:-

```
public class Items
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public string DataTable1 { get; set; }
    public string DataTable2 { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. But when i am trying to integrate. I have got an issue for "TypeDescriptor". 

Like "The name TypeDescriptor does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @LakshminarayananE - Please include `using System.ComponentModel;` namespace.

Comment: Now it is showing error "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class" in this class.   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

Comment: @lakshminarayanana- please include that extension method in a static class!

Comment: Sorry again it is throwing the same error. Please check ID is a Identity column, It is similar like SI.No.

Comment: @LakshminarayananE - Same error as in? "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"?

Comment: Yes it is throwing "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"

Comment: @LakshminarayananE - That's what i asked you to do, wrap that complete method `PropertiesToDataTable` in a static class.

Comment: Please go through this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604787/compare-2-datatables-and-store-the-differences-in-another-datatable-using-linq/27609965#27609965

Comment: @RahulSingh, good solution. I think it's not worth to help people who don't want to learn and asking the same question over and over again (even on other programming forums, like CodeProject).

Answer (score 0):

I have written in two query to achieve what you said..Perhaps you can optimize it further.

```
//datatable1
         DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

        dt1.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Weight");

        DataRow dr ;

        dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = 1;
        dr["Name"] = "Ship";
        dr["Weight"] = 500;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);


        dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = 2;
        dr["Name"] = "Train";
        dr["Weight"] = 600;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);


        dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = 3;
        dr["Name"] = "Plane";
        dr["Weight"] = 700;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = 4;
        dr["Name"] = "Car";
        dr["Weight"] = 400;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

         //datatable2
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Weight");
        DataRow dr2;
        dr2 = dt2.NewRow();
        dr2["Id"] = 1;
        dr2["Name"] = "Ship";
        dr2["Weight"] = 500;
        dt2.Rows.Add(dr2);

        dr2 = dt2.NewRow();
        dr2["Id"] = 3;
        dr2["Name"] = "Plane";
        dr2["Weight"] = 700;
        dt2.Rows.Add(dr2);

        dr2 = dt2.NewRow();
        dr2["Id"] = 4;
        dr2["Name"] = "Car";
        dr2["Weight"] = 400;
        dt2.Rows.Add(dr2);

        //iterate through table1
        IEnumerable<DataRow> table1 = from r in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                      select r;

        //iterate through table2
        IEnumerable<DataRow> table2 = from r in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                      select r;

        Console.WriteLine("Id\tName\tWeight\tDatatable1\tDatatable2");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
        //prints the common records
        foreach (DataRow td1 in table1.Distinct())//Matches wholes of the Element Sequence inside IEnumerable
        {
            table2.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(td2 =>
            {
                if (td1.Field<string>("Id") == td2.Field<string>("Id"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(td1.Field<string>("Id") + "\t" + td1.Field<string>("Name") + "\t" + td1.Field<string>("Weight") + "\t" + "x" + "\t\t" + "x");
                }
            });
        }
        //prints the missing records
        var query = (from tb1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                     join tb2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                     on tb1.Field<string>("Id") equals tb2.Field<string>("Id") into subset
                     from sc in subset.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where sc == null
                     select new
                     {
                         id = tb1.Field<string>("Id"),
                         name = tb1.Field<string>("Name"),
                         wt = tb1.Field<string>("Weight")
                     }).Distinct();

        foreach (var td1 in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(td1.id + "\t" + td1.name + "\t" + td1.wt + "\t" + "x" + "\t\t" + "-");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, But it should compare both the tables & result should be displayed in both the tables. If the value is in both the tables. X shold be in both tables.