# C# Linq GroupBy method works different for anonymous vs non-anonymous types

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a DataTable with 4 columns as follows:

```
    private static DataSet dataSet;
    private const string tableName = "MyTable";
    private const string columnName1 = "Supplier";  //Column names
    private const string columnName2 = "Invoice";
    private const string columnName3 = "Item";
    private const string columnName4 = "Amount";
```

I grouped the table by Supplier, Invoice columns and calculated the sum for the Amount using the following linq query:

```
    private static DataTable GroupQueryA(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        DataTable groupedTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new { Key1 = r.Field<string>(columnName1), Key2 = r.Field<string>(columnName2) })
            .Select(g => new GroupSum
            {
                Key1 = g.Key.Key1,
                Key2 = g.Key.Key2,
                Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>(columnName4))
            }).PropertiesToDataTable<GroupSum>();

        return groupedTable;
    }
```

The GroupSum type I declared as:

```
    private class GroupSum
    {
        public string Key1 { get; set; }
        public string Key2 { get; set; }
        public Double Sum { get; set; }
    }
```

The PropertiesToDataTable() method I copied from :

[Convert Datatable GroupBy Multiple Columns with Sum using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378537/convert-datatable-groupby-multiple-columns-with-sum-using-linq)

It works perfect so that for the table rows like:

```
    AddRow(dataTable, "SA", "INVA", "ITA", 10);
    AddRow(dataTable, "SA", "INVA", "ITB", 20);
    AddRow(dataTable, "SB", "INVB", "ITC", 50);
```

I receive 2 rows in the result:

```
    "SA", "INVA", 30
    "SB", "INVB", 50
```

However I decided to modify my query so that instead of using the anonymous type  I coded the :

```
    public class GroupKeys
    {
        public string Key1 { get; set; }
        public string Key2 { get; set; }
    }
```

and the query.

```
    private static DataTable GroupQueryB(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        DataTable groupedTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new GroupKeys { Key1 = r.Field<string>(columnName1), Key2 = r.Field<string>(columnName2) })
            .Select(g => new GroupSum
            {
                Key1 = g.Key.Key1,
                Key2 = g.Key.Key2,
                Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>(columnName4))
            }).PropertiesToDataTable<GroupSum>();

        return groupedTable;
    }
```

And now for the same source data I receive different result:

```
    "SA", "INVA", 10
    "SA", "INVA", 20
    "SB", "INVB", 50
```

It seems that the source data is not grouped at all athough the only difference in the query is one line:

```
    //QueryA
    .GroupBy(r => new { Key1 = r.Field<string>(columnName1), Key2 = r.Field<string>(columnName2) })
    //QueryB
    .GroupBy(r => new GroupKeys { Key1 = r.Field<string>(columnName1), Key2 = r.Field<string>(columnName2) })
```

Could anybody explain that please ?
For those who would like to run the test in the Visual Studio please find the complete source below.

```
internal static class TestForStackOverflow
{
    private static DataSet dataSet;
    private const string tableName = "MyTable";
    private const string columnName1 = "Supplier";  //Column names
    private const string columnName2 = "Invoice";
    private const string columnName3 = "Item";
    private const string columnName4 = "Amount";

    private class GroupKeys
    {
        public string Key1 { get; set; }
        public string Key2 { get; set; }
    }

    private class GroupSum
    {
        public string Key1 { get; set; }
        public string Key2 { get; set; }
        public Double Sum { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = InitializeDataTable();

        //DataTable groupedTable = GroupQueryA(dataTable);      //Please uncomment to run test A
        DataTable groupedTable = GroupQueryB(dataTable);        //Please uncomment to run test B

        DisplayData(groupedTable);
    }


    private static DataTable GroupQueryA(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        DataTable groupedTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new { Key1 = r.Field<string>(columnName1), Key2 = r.Field<string>(columnName2) })
            .Select(g => new GroupSum
            {
                Key1 = g.Key.Key1,
                Key2 = g.Key.Key2,
                Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>(columnName4))
            }).PropertiesToDataTable<GroupSum>();

        return groupedTable;
    }

    private static DataTable GroupQueryB(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        DataTable groupedTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new GroupKeys { Key1 = r.Field<string>(columnName1), Key2 = r.Field<string>(columnName2) })
            .Select(g => new GroupSum
            {
                Key1 = g.Key.Key1,
                Key2 = g.Key.Key2,
                Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>(columnName4))
            }).PropertiesToDataTable<GroupSum>();

        return groupedTable;
    }

    private static System.Data.DataTable PropertiesToDataTable<T>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        //Weź listę właściwości typu <T> i dla każdej właściwości dodaj do tabeli kolumnę tego samego typu co właściwość
        var props = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        {
            System.Data.DataColumn dc = dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            dc.Caption = prop.DisplayName;
            dc.ReadOnly = prop.IsReadOnly;
        }
        //Kopiuj rekordy z kwerendy do DataTable
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                dr[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    private static DataTable InitializeDataTable()
    {
        dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add(tableName);

        dataTable.Columns.Add( columnName1, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add( columnName2, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add( columnName3, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add( columnName4, typeof(double));

        AddRow(dataTable, "SA", "INVA", "ITA", 10);
        AddRow(dataTable, "SA", "INVA", "ITB", 20);
        AddRow(dataTable, "SB", "INVB", "ITC", 50);
        return dataTable;
    }
    private static void AddRow( DataTable dataTable, string supplier, string invoice, string item, double amount)
    {
        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
        row[columnName1] = supplier;
        row[columnName2] = invoice;
        row[columnName3] = item;
        row[columnName4] = amount;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    private static void DisplayData(System.Data.DataTable table)
    {
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("============================");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because C# compiler correctly implements `GetHashCode` / `Equals` for anonymous types. While for your own type you should implement them yourself. Which you didn't, hence the `GroupBy` difference.

Comment: The second method you are grouping by a class {new GroupKeys} which doesn't have a ICompare method.  The first method you are actually comparing three strings.

Comment: Consider overriding the Equals and GetHashCode methods on GroupSum class. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363143/whats-the-best-strategy-for-equals-and-gethashcode

Comment: ^ Did not know that this was because of GetHashCode/Equals. Always thought it worked because it passes through to sql as a group by a, b, c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to touch up your GroupKeys object a little bit more. Since it's a reference type, and GroupBy is using the [Default Equality Comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx), part of it's check is going to be testing for referential equality, which will always return false.

You can adjust your GroupKeys class by overriding the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to test for structural equality. As an example, this is generated by ReSharper:

```
private class GroupKeys
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((Key1 != null ? Key1.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ (Key2 != null ? Key2.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
            return false;

        return Equals((GroupKeys)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(GroupKeys other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return string.Equals(Key1, other.Key1)
               && string.Equals(Key2, other.Key2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer solved my issue. I modified your solution a little bit.

        private class GroupKeys : IEquatable<GroupKeys>

I did not implement the method: public bool Equals(object obj)